# Unable to find class HBox while using Java 8 update 60 with javafx

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I have installed Java 8 update 60 which includes Javafx as well.

I am able to see the javafx classes being imported but unable to find HBox Class under javafx.scene.layout package

It is showing me the deprecated HBoxBuilder. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Maybe they mistakenly removed HBoxes instead of HBoxBuilders ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using 8u60 early access.
I've checked - HBox.class exists in jdk_home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar (linux x64)
Please open jfxrt.jar in archive manager and check it.

What platform do you use?

It looks like you have not switched jdk in your ide

Answer (score 0):

Holy Cow, the HBox class was there in the JAR in JAVAfx-8 u60. It was my old eclipse classic that was unable to show. Sounds absurd, but this is what happened. I am using Eclipse Mars now and able to see.